# VirtualBox Debian Jessie guest has invisible mouse after update

Tags: virtualbox, debian, mouse

After updating the system with **apt-get upgrade**, the mouse disappeared in my guest environment. I use the guest additions and the other features work (like high resolution X sessions), but my mouse cursor is invisible: I can click around but I can't see it.

How do I debug this?

```
VirtualBox at host: 4.3.12
VirtualBox at guest: 4.3.14
Linux kernel version: 3.14
```

I've already tried

```
dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

It rebuilt the modules but the mouse kept being invisible after a reboot. I'm out of options right now.

Answer (score 3):

Gnome 3 was the culprit. After some googling, the solution was to change its configuration like this:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/cursor/active false
```

Reference: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171595